# how to search for a field based on an input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list of objects displayed in UI.
I have to search by a field, for example 'name'.

```
'name': 'THE TERA COMPANY'
```

If the user types 'tera' i should display all the objects with 'THE TERA COMPANY'
What i have tried displays those objects only if the user types exactly the same name.

Bellow is what I have tried so far with includes() method

```
  searchInputChanged(input) {
    this.filters.searchBy = input;
    this.loading = true;
    this.allItems= this.filter();
  }


filter() {
    const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.fallBackItems));

    Object.keys(result).forEach(key => {
      if (this.filters.searchBy && this.filters.searchBy.length) {
        result[key] = result[key].filter(r =>
          this.filters.searchBy.includes(r.id) ||
          this.filters.searchBy.includes(r.name));
      }
    });

    this.loading = false;
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: `r.name.includes(this.filters.searchBy)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct with includes but it changes the keys in reverse

```
filter() {
  let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.fallBackItems));

  if (this.filters.searchBy && this.filters.searchBy.length) {
    result = Object
     .entries(result)
     .filter(([, { id, name }]) =>
       id.toLowerCase().includes(this.filter.searchBy.toLowerCase()) ||
       name.toLowerCase().includes(this.filter.searchBy.toLowerCase())
     )
     .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
       acc[key] = value;

       return acc;
     }, {});
  }

  this.loading = false;
  return result;
}
```